# Transfer AdMob earnings to campaign

Tags: android, admob

I have published an App on google play and inegrated AdMob into it.
I have made a little money from admob, and now I want to use it in a campaign to promote my app.

However, I can't figure out how to transfer money from earnings to ad funds.

I've searched on google and people seam to be able to do it, but I couldn't find out how.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was possible, but it isn't anymore. Add funds Using a creditcard.